# Просмотр содержимого массива при отладке в Viusal Studio Win32 Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Допустим, есть такой код:

```
BYTE var1[6] = {0x12, 0x00, 0x2c, 0x00, 0xab, 0x00};
BYTE *var2 = new BYTE[6];
memcpy(var2, var1, 6);

//* breakpoint
```

Проблема в том, что при достижении точки останова при попытке посмотреть содержимое **var2** в окнах Locals, Autos, Watch, а также во всплывающей подсказке студия даёт информацию только о первом (в данном случае) байте, как будто интерпретируя содержимое массива как текстовую строку у которой следующий байт (в данном случае второй) является нуль-терминатором:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос**: как при отладке посмотреть фактическое содержимое **var2**? В каких окнах или режимах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отладка->Быстрая проверка, ну или просто Shift-F9 и вводите там "var2, 6".

Answer (score 1):

Открываете окошко просмотра переменных Main menu -> Debug -> Watch -> Watch1. Добавляете туда выражение `var2[2]` для просмотра элемента по индексу или `*((unsigned char (*) [6]) var2)` для просмотра массива целиком.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]